# Error using jQuery with django: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-2.1

I am trying to use jQuery with my django app but when I use the inspector and look at the .js file in Sources, I am seeing this error.  I know this question has come up before, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it in my case.  This is the HTML for the page I am trying to load:

```
{% extends 'great_songs_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'great_songs_app/playlist_jquery.js' %}"> 
</script>
--code--
{% endblock %
```

And this is my base HTML file:

```html
{% load static %}
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://rsms.me/inter/inter-ui.css" rel="preload" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'great_songs_app/style.css' %}">
   <title>Great Songs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'great_songs:great_songs' %}">Great Songs</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:great_songs' %}">Songs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:artists' %}">Artists</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:genres' %}">Genres</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:producers' %}">Producers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:labels' %}">Labels</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'great_songs:playlists' %}">Playlists</a>
          </li>
        </ul> 
        <ul class="navbar-nav" id="login-list">  
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li class="nav-item login">  
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:logout' %}" id=login>log out</a>
            </li>  
          {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item login">  
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:login' %}" id=login>log in</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item login">  
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:register' %}">register</a>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my jQuery file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".playlist-row").click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery script included properly?

Comment: you mean including my .js file?

Comment: the jquery script itself

Comment: edited my question to include js file

Comment: jQuery needs to be loaded in the document **before** your script tries to use it. Try moving your _content_ block below the `<script>` tags

Comment: I tried that and now the .js file doesn't seem to get loaded at all

Comment: add `<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
` (or whatever jQuery version you are using)  in the beginning of `<head>` of base.html .

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and just I pasted the `js` files inside `head` tag.

Here is my `base.html`
[image]
Then inside `body` tag, the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`.